# Python: Filtering sublists based on maximum value spread

Tags: python

I have a list of lists. Each sublist contains 2 items, and for n occurences, second item of the sublist is the same.

I want to keep only the first sublist, because spread is the largest in the first one. Here's what I have:

```
[[0, 3],
 [1, 3],
 [2, 3],
 [314, 335],
 [315, 335],
 [316, 335],
 [317, 335],
 [318, 335],
 [319, 335],
 [320, 335],
 [321, 335],
 [322, 335],
 [323, 335],
 [324, 335],
 [325, 335],
 [326, 335],
 [327, 335],
 [328, 335],
 [329, 335],
 [330, 335],
 [331, 335],
 [332, 335],
 [333, 335],
 [334, 335],
 [645, 647],
 [646, 647]]
```

And I want to keep:

```
[[0, 3],
[314, 335],
[645, 647]]
```

Any ideas on how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
seen = set()
result = []
for i in data:
    if i[1] not in seen:    #Check if second item in set
        result.append(i)    #Add to result
        seen.add(i[1])      #Add second item to set

print(result) #--> [[0, 3], [314, 335], [645, 647]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) could be used:

```
from itertools import groupby

ret = [[next(group)[0], key] for key, group in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])]
# [[0, 3], [314, 335], [645, 647]]
```

where i use the second element in your sublists as `key`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is using pandas data frames

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(your_data)

df2 = df.drop_duplicates(1)
```

a data frame that can then be converted back into a list.

Comment: that is elegant!

Answer (score 0):

There is ready recipe in [itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for that task:

```
import itertools
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element

data = [[0, 3],
 [1, 3],
 [2, 3],
 [314, 335],
 [315, 335],
 [316, 335],
 [317, 335],
 [318, 335],
 [319, 335],
 [320, 335],
 [321, 335],
 [322, 335],
 [323, 335],
 [324, 335],
 [325, 335],
 [326, 335],
 [327, 335],
 [328, 335],
 [329, 335],
 [330, 335],
 [331, 335],
 [332, 335],
 [333, 335],
 [334, 335],
 [645, 647],
 [646, 647]]
out = list(unique_everseen(data,key=lambda x:x[1]))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3], [314, 335], [645, 647]]
```